# Sharing a folder of contents between multiple projects (Visual Studio)

Tags: visual-studio

I want to share a folder of general contents between 2 projects (Such as classes, files, etc). I've tried adding the folders individually but its very time consuming and it doesn't give the expected results when using file linking.

I recently came across MonoGame, when inspecting the project in Visual Studio it appears to be doing EXACTLY what I want but I can't figure out how this process has been done as I'm no expert with Visual Studio.

Here is an image example
[image]

On the left is the MonoGame project opened as a folder (Not a solution or project)
which contains multiple projects & solutions that share the folder "MonoGame.Framework" and it's contents.

On the right is the one of the many solutions available in the MonoGame project, I chose the MonoGame.Framework.Android at random. When opened you can see the "MonoGame.Framework" folder is included. If I make any changes in either project the changes are reflected across all projects, for example adding new files or editing code.

It doesn't appear to be using typical file linking in visual studio as no link icon is next to the files, and whenever I add a new file its automatically included in all other projects without manually adding it.

How is this behaviour done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer myself.

- Create an empty folder "C:\Main"
- Create Project 1 Solution inside "C:\Main"
- Create Project 2 Solution inside "C:\Main"

> "C:\Main" folder should look like this
> [image]

- Create a folder "C:\Main\Framework"
- Open Project 1 solution, Create a Library project I've named mine "Project1" inside "Framework" folder, save & close visual studio.
- Go into Framework folder, then into Project1 folder, Move "Project1.csproj" file into Framework then delete the Project1.csproj folder
- Repeat exact steps for Project 2

> "C:\Main\Framework" folder should now look like this
> [image]

Now open both projects. Any files added to the framework folder will appear in both projects automatically and any modifications will be reflected across projects.